# Adjusting y-scales in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to adjust the y-scale, which should start from `5` and end at `-5`and remove all the data point from this scale
I tried this code

```
pd = position_dodge(width = 0.5)
ggplot(dt, aes(fill=Treatment, y= value, x=variable)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",width = 0.25, position = pd)+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.4, position = pd, outlier.shape = NA)+ 
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.2,jitter.height = 0.8,dodge.width=0.5),
              shape=21, size=0.3, alpha=0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CF9FFF","#800080"))+
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = Treatment),method = "anova", label = "p.signif",
                     label.y = c(2.15,2.55,2.7,2.3,2.7,2.7),size=3.5,
                     symnum.args = list(cutpoints = c(0,0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf),
                                        symbols=c("***","**","*","ns")))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black", face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black", face="bold"),
        legend.position = c(0.15, 0.05), legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9, face="italic", colour = "black")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-5,5,1),labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.01))
```

[image]
but it create this plot.

Comment: Rather than setting the `scale_y_continous` breaks, try adding `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-5,5))`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Remove any themes or other code not essential to the problem to make the code as minimal as possible so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for above -
if you use
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(ymin, ymax))
it zooms in on the data where as
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(ymin, ymax))

so if this is what you want to do add the limits statement

you actually delete the data outside of the range which would change you box plots... a way to remove outliers but also rather dangerous